# Can a professor accuse a student of cheating on an exam without witnessing it firsthand?

Tags: exams, cheating

Can a professor accuse someone of cheating after checking his or her test? How is that possible, if the professor has not caught the student cheating red-handed?

Comment: To get more informative answers, you will have to include at least a few more details about the situation. You can edit the question freely to add them. In particular, the systems are very different in different countries, so saying which country you are interested in will give better answers.

Comment: I am referring to UK.

Comment: The general answer to the question is "Yes." There are a lot of reasons why a professor might suspect a student of cheating, some of which do not require an eyewitness. You'll have to give more details (i.e., what did the professor say/do? why does the professor suspect cheating?) in order to get a helpful answer.

Comment: oi think she suspects because people might have the same answers. but can she accuse someone if she didn't even catch them doing it? how can she accuse them when she has not even seen them doing it?

Comment: what can be the consequences of cheating on a test?

Comment: @usman: Consequences?  Anything from a zero on the exam to expulsion from the university.  You're going to have to provide more detail if you want better answers.

Comment: Is this a question, or a complaint?  Do you really want a literal answer to the "how is it possible" question?

Comment: There are certainly situations where I can be quite sure a student cheated on an exam. Two students, who sat next to each other during the exam, turn in papers containing proofs that are almost identical, except that one has correct proofs while the other has a few isolated words that are different, similar (so that they could be miscopied), and make no sense in the context.

Answer (score 7):

Generally speaking, the answer to your question is "Yes."

If there is a strong similarity in answers that is highly unlikely if the students worked independently, it can raise suspicions of cheating.

For example, in [Reilly v. Daly](http://leagle.com/decision/19961105666NE2d439_11085.xml/REILLY%20v.%20DALY),

> At the conclusion of the exam period, the professors held the exam papers of Reilly and the neighboring student in order to determine whether their answers matched. A comparison of the exams revealed that the first seven pages, which included twenty-seven multiple choice and matching questions, were identical.
>
> ...
>
> Taking the conservative approach of comparing only wrong answers on only the multiple choice questions, the professors were advised by a statistician that there was a one in 200,000 probability that such a match of wrong answers on the multiple choice questions would occur by chance.
>
> ...
>
> Reilly also presented her own statistical analysis of the exam and brought to the professors' attention the possibility of "lure" questions on the exam which would heighten the probability of the match occurring by chance. The professors thereafter obtained a new statistical analysis taking into account "lure" questions on the exam. This analysis demonstrated a one in 500 to one in 5000 probability of the match occurring by chance.

Whether this kind of evidence is enough to initiate disciplinary proceedings, and what the consequences could be, depends entirely on the detailed specifics of the scenario and the university policy.

For example, in [Papelino v. Albany College of Pharmacy vs Union University](http://caselaw.findlaw.com/us-2nd-circuit/1553600.html), while similar statistical evidence raised suspicions, it was not considered sufficient to *conclude* that the students had cheated.

Comment: These court cases are interesting but I'm worried that focusing on the legal system might give OP the wrong impression.  My understanding is that it would be very unusual for the courts to get involved when a professor accuses a student of cheating.  (Of course the student can try to sue to school but this is almost always just a waste of time.)  Although plaintiffs won in _Papelino_ I would guess this is not relevant to the OP because that was a Title IX retaliation claim.

Comment: @Trevor Sure. The point is that suspicions may be raised just by looking at the exam paper. The court records happen to provide several examples of this. (Generally academic dishonesty proceedings are not publicly available unless it happens to go to court.)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the case, but I'd say that there's a good chance that in, say, thirty years of US university tests you'll get a couple of 200k to 1 coincidences. It reminds me of the [Sally Clark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sally_Clark) case (albeit a little less depressing).

Comment: Here is one way to catch someone cheating without seeing them do it.   Plagiarism.  You have no idea how many times in online courses I see fellow classmates simply copy paste from sources and not cite them, but in my experience, I get professors that ignore plagiarism for some reason and do not enforce the honor code.  Usually they are tenured, the adjuncts are bit more on the ball

Comment: @NZKshatriya: On the other hand I have seen documentation of identical student work in computer science being confirmed to be independent.